# Invalid Escape Character in Regex for html 5 Input Validation

Tags: regex, html

Chrome is telling me there is an invalid escape character in this regex which has worked fine for a long time in the past. I can't spot what needs to be done to make it a valid-escaped regex for use in html5 form validation attributes.

Originally it was this (line break for easier reading)

```
^(?:(?:[hH]{1}[tT]{2}[pP]{1})(?:S|s)?:\/\/)?[\w\-_]+
(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?$
```

Until I escaped the ampersand with `\x26`

```
^(?:(?:[hH]{1}[tT]{2}[pP]{1})(?:S|s)?:\/\/)?[\w\-_]+
(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%\x26amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%\x26amp;/~\+#])?$
```

The original used to work fine for html5 input validation but chrome doesn't like either of them now.

I can't spot what it would be...

Comment: What is this supposed to match, just out of curiosity?

Comment: Oh, it is for an application-specific url format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both the cases, I believe you had unnecessarily escaped the `@` character, which apparently is not valid in HTML5

**Below are the correct RegExs**

```regex
^(?:(?:[hH]{1}[tT]{2}[pP]{1})(?:S|s)?:\/\/)?[\w\-_]+
(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?$

^(?:(?:[hH]{1}[tT]{2}[pP]{1})(?:S|s)?:\/\/)?[\w\-_]+
(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%\x26amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-@?^=%\x26amp;/~\+#])?$
```